# Python Pandas change values from a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how are you? I'm pretty new at code, and I have this question:

I want to iterate through a column, and I want to change this column values based on a condition, in this case, I want to change very value from column 'a1': if the value contains the word 'Juancito' I want to change it to just 'Juancito'.
The for loop works OK, but the value doesn't change in the end.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'a1':'Juancito 1'}, {'a1':'Juancito 2'}, {'a1':'Juancito 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

for i in df['a1']:
    if 'Juancito' in i:
        i = 'Juancito'
    else:
        pass
df.head()
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to make `Juancito' ` if it is already `Juancito' `. Also `if 'Juancito' in i` , do you want to use `is` or `==` operator? `i = 'Juancito'`, here you are just changing the variable `i` but not the actual dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need a `for` loop.**

Just use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [83]: import numpy as np

In [84]: df['a1'] = np.where(df['a1'].str.contains('Juancito'), 'Juancito', df['a1'])

In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
         a1
0  Juancito
1  Juancito
2  Juancito
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'a1':'Juancito 1'}, {'a1':'Juancito 2'}, {'a1':'Juancito 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

for i in range(df["a1"].shape[0]):
    print(i)
    if 'Juancito' in df["a1"][i]:
        df["a1"][i] = 'Juancito'
    else:
        pass
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the value of the dataframe element in your code. You are just assigning it temporarily to i.
One approach would be to use numeric indexing where row number will change with i and column number would be the one you want to process.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'a1':'Juancito 1'}, {'a1':'Juancito 2'}, {'a1':'Juancito 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if 'Juancito' in df.iloc[i][0]:
        df.iloc[i][0] = 'Juancito'
    else:
        pass
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, incorporated the changes

```py
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'a1':'Juancito 1'}, {'a1':'Juancito 2'}, {'a1':'Juancito 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

for index, i in enumerate(df['a1'])::
    if 'Juancito' == i:
        df['a1'].loc[index] = 'Juancito'
    else:
        pass
df.head()
```